# c program, warning message passing argument 1 of ‘fstat’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, warnings, stat

I'm getting back into c after a long hiatus. Here's a little program I've written to output a files size. It compiles, and it works correctly, and it's pretty much copied and pasted from the man page. But it gives me an annoying warning from gcc.

```
gcc -ggdb  read_file_to_char_array.c -o read_file_to_char_array `mysql_config --cflags --libs && pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 && pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl`  
read_file_to_char_array.c: In function ‘main’:
read_file_to_char_array.c:22:19: warning:   [enabled by default]
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:216:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’`
```

Any hints as to how I can make it go away (without disabling warnings ;) )

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long *lengths;
    FILE *fp;
    struct stat sb;

    fp = fopen("image.png", "rb");
    fstat(fp,&sb);

    printf(" Size - %lld : ", (long long)sb.st_size);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: I only count 20 lines in your program, so I can't see which line the warning is referring to - mind posting the whole thing, maybe on [pastebin](www.pastebin.com)?

Comment: +1 for using "rb" for an image file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to [**pass a file descriptor**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html), not a `FILE *`.

> `int fstat(int fildes, struct stat *buf);`

Try using [`fileno(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) to get the file descriptor from a `FILE *`.

```
int fd;

fp = fopen("image.png", "rb");
fd = fileno(fp);

fstat(fd, &sb);
```

Comment: Man, that error message was totally misleading, I thought the problem was caused by &sb

Comment: 'fileno' is exactly what I was after. Thanks!